# What might have caused this error "x cell sizes are not regular"?

Tags: r, error, classification

I am doing a landuse classification. I tried to convert values to raster using this:

```
x<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(as.data.frame(grid.data)[, c("x", "y")], data = grid.data)

r <- rasterFromXYZ(as.data.frame(x)[, c("x", "y", "Class_ID")])
```

I am confronted with this error:

```
Error in rasterFromXYZ(as.data.frame(x)[, c("x", "y", "Class_ID")]) : 
x cell sizes are not regular
```

What is meant by "not regular"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rasters represent an equally spaced array. This error is saying that your xy coordinates do not represent equal cell spacing. If you want to convert an irregular spacing of points to a raster than you need to use a rasterization type function.

You are approaching the problem using a library `sp`, and associated object classes, that is being depreciated in leu of `sf`. For raster object classes you should be using `terra`. It is plausible that the regularity issue is related to decimal precision.  I would reccomend performing this conversion, coersion, rasterization using terra with an sf point object. Since we know nothing of your data that is about all I can reccomend, which is why " reproducible examples" are prefered.